# Create CheckBoxListCell with custom background color in JavaFx 8

Tags: listview, javafx-8

I am trying to modify an example of the use of the CheckBoxListCell in order to add custom background color to every Cell. Here is what I 've done so far but to no avail

```
// ListViewCheckBoxEditing.java
package application;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewCheckBoxEditing extends Application {
    Map<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Populate the map with ListView items as its keys and 
        // their selected state as the value 
        map.put("Apple", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Banana", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Donut", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Hash Brown", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));

        ListView<String> breakfasts = new ListView<>();
        breakfasts.setPrefSize(200, 120);
        breakfasts.setEditable(true);
        breakfasts.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // Add all keys from the map as items to the ListView       
        breakfasts.getItems().addAll(map.keySet());

        // Create a Callback object
        Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>> itemToBoolean = (String item) -> map.get(item);

        // Set the cell factory to my CheckBoxListCell implementation
        breakfasts.setCellFactory(MyCell.forListView(itemToBoolean));

        Button printBtn = new Button("Print Selection");
        printBtn.setOnAction(e -> printSelection());

        VBox root = new VBox(new Label("Breakfasts:"), breakfasts, printBtn);   
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        stage.setScene(scene);      
        stage.setTitle("Using ListView Cell Factory");
        stage.show();
    }

    public void printSelection() {
        System.out.println("Selected items: ");
        for(String key: map.keySet()) {
            ObservableValue<Boolean> value = map.get(key);
            if (value.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(key);        
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public class MyCell extends CheckBoxListCell<String>{
        public MyCell(){
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            // I would expect the following to work
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes a really pleasant change to see a well-written question that includes an actual [MCVE] that demonstrates the issue. Upvoting.

Comment: Thank you for answering and upvoting. To be fair, the example was hacked from [this book](http://www.apress.com/9781484211434)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static method call `MyCell.forListView(..)` simply invokes the method `CheckBoxListCell.forListView(...)`, so you are not using your custom cell class at all.

For the functionality you want, you can simply change the style of the cell that's returned from that method:

```
// Set the cell factory to my CheckBoxListCell implementation

Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> defaultCellFactory = CheckBoxListCell.forListView(itemToBoolean);

breakfasts.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<String> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(lv);
    cell.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
    return cell ;
});
```

and remove your cell implementation entirely.

If you need something more complex, that really requires an override of the `updateItem(...)` method, you need to implement the callback to return an instance of your cell subclass:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewCheckBoxEditing extends Application {
    Map<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // Populate the map with ListView items as its keys and 
        // their selected state as the value 
        map.put("Apple", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Banana", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Donut", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        map.put("Hash Brown", new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));

        ListView<String> breakfasts = new ListView<>();
        breakfasts.setPrefSize(200, 120);
        breakfasts.setEditable(true);
        breakfasts.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // Add all keys from the map as items to the ListView       
        breakfasts.getItems().addAll(map.keySet());

        // Create a Callback object
        Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>> itemToBoolean = (String item) -> map.get(item);

        // Set the cell factory to my CheckBoxListCell implementation
        breakfasts.setCellFactory(lv -> new MyCell(itemToBoolean));

        Button printBtn = new Button("Print Selection");
        printBtn.setOnAction(e -> printSelection());

        VBox root = new VBox(new Label("Breakfasts:"), breakfasts, printBtn);   
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);      
        stage.setScene(scene);      
        stage.setTitle("Using ListView Cell Factory");
        stage.show();
    }

    public void printSelection() {
        System.out.println("Selected items: ");
        for(String key: map.keySet()) {
            ObservableValue<Boolean> value = map.get(key);
            if (value.getValue()) {
                System.out.println(key);        
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public class MyCell extends CheckBoxListCell<String>{
        public MyCell(Callback<String, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedProperty){
            super(getSelectedProperty);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            // I would expect the following to work
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense now! I intend to go with the custom class thank you!